# Setting up angular project with puphpet, creating a virtual host

Tags: angularjs, apache, vagrant, virtual-machine, puphpet

I recently started using VM's for development but I lack skills on setting up virtual hosts and using apache/nginx.

So I have a project now in two parts. Backend is created with Laravel and frontend with AngularJS. I'm using Apache in my VM.

I managed to set up virtual host for the backend with no problems. Now I'm having troubles on setting up a virtual host for AngularJS. I know I can run it with gulp serve, which in my case hosts it at `localhost:9001`. But that means I can access it in my virtual machine with that url. How can I access it from my machine? If my virtual machine url is `192.168.56.101`, shouldn't I be able to access it from `192.168.56.101:9001`? Right now it just says:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 192.168.56.101 took too long to respond.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to open up the port in the firewall section.